# How to fix text size for all tables within a section?

Tags: tables, overleaf, adjustbox, column-width

I have several tables in my article. Unfortunately, the text size in the tables differ quite substantially. I would like to have all the tables with exactly the same text size but also with the same column with. How can I do this?
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makecell, booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!] \centering
\resizebox{8cm}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|l{5cm}|c{3cm}|}
\hline
variable (in log) & ablablablablablablabablablablablablablab\\
\hline
blablablablablablablabla & 0.03\\
ablablab & 0.29\\
blablablablablablablablablablablabla & -0.47\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!] \centering
\resizebox{8cm}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|l{5cm}|c{3cm}|}
\hline
variable (in log) & ablablab\\
\hline
ablablab & 0.03\\
ablablab & 0.29\\
ablablab & -0.47\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: latex would never do that, you are forcing inconsistent font sizes by using `\resizebox`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- don't use `\resizebox`!
- prescribe the same column width in all tables and by this allow that cells contents can be broken into many lines.

For example, by use of the `tabularray` package with libraries `booktabs` and `siunitx`  (which loads packages of the same name), your tables are:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht] 
\centering
\begin{tblr}{vlines,
             colspec={Q[l,wd=5cm] Q[c,wd=3cm, si={table-format=-1.2}]}
             }
    \toprule
variable (in log)   & {{{abla blablabl ablabl ab ablabla blablab lablab}}}  \\
    \midrule
bla bla bla blabla blabl abla 
                    & 0.03      \\
ablablab            & 0.29      \\
blabla blabla blablabla bla blablablabla 
                    & -0.47     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht] 
\centering
\begin{tblr}{vlines,
             colspec={Q[l,wd=5cm] Q[c,wd=3cm, si={table-format=-1.2}]}
             }
    \toprule
variable (in log)   & {{{ablablab}}} \\
    \midrule
ablablab            & 0.03\\
ablablab            & 0.29\\
ablablab            & -0.47\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]